# Is there a way to display different strings based on a switch statement that are coming from an input field

Tags: javascript, html, input, switch-statement

In the program I am writing the user can add a part to a queue and the most recent part is displayed in a separate div. What I am trying to do is get the value of the input for displaying the part and show more details of the part but using a switch statement  to change the information depending on what the user enters.

I have seen examples using switch with strings before, but not if the value is from an input. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code.

```js
let queue = [];
let compPart = [];

const partsInput = document.getElementById("parts");
const arrDisplay = document.getElementById("arr");
const completeDisplay = document.getElementById("compDisp");
const newestDisplay = document.getElementById("disp");
const logArea = document.getElementById("logList");
const partDetail = document.getElementById("details");

switch (partsInput) {
case 'Gear':
document.getElementById("details").innerHTML = 'Width: 5, Length: 2, Thickness: 1';
break;
case 'Screw':
document.getElementById("details").innerHTML = 'Width: 2, Length: 1, Thickness: 1';
break;
case 'Tube':
document.getElementById("details").innerHTML = 'Width: 3, Length: 8, Thickness: 2';
break;
case 'Socket':
document.getElementById("details").innerHTML = 'Width: 10, Length: 3, Thickness: 5';
break;
default:
document.getElementById("details").innerHTML = "Not a correct type of part";
}

function queuePart() {
  queue.push(partsInput.value);
  partsInput.value = ''; //Clear input when added
  partsInput.focus(); 
  if (queue.length > 4) {
    queue.shift();
  }
  arrDisplay.innerHTML = queue;
  newestDisplay.innerHTML = queue.at(-1); 
  logArea.innerHTML += "A part was added at this Date and Time" + "<br>" + Date() + "<br><br>";
}

function completePart() {
  if (queue.length == 0) return; //Do nothing if queue is empty
  
  compPart.push(queue.pop());
  completeDisplay.innerHTML = compPart;
  arrDisplay.innerHTML = queue;

  if (queue.length > 0) {
    newestDisplay.innerHTML = queue.at(-1); 
  } else {
    newestDisplay.innerHTML = 'Currently No Parts In Queue';
  }
  logArea.innerHTML += "A part was completed at this Date and Time" + "<br>" + Date() + "<br><br>";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Machine Web UI</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  
  <body>        
    </div>
    <div class="display" id="screen1">
      <h1>Queue Area</h1>
      <pre id="arr">Currently No Parts In Queue</pre>
      <input type ="text" id ="parts"></input>
      <button type="button" onclick="queuePart()"> Add a Part </button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="container" id="screen2">
      <h1>Part Display Area</h1>
      <pre id="disp"></pre> <br>
      <pre id="details"></pre>
<button type="button" id="btn" onclick="completePart()"> Complete Part </button>        
    </div>
    
    <div class="display" id="screen3">
      <h1>Completed Parts Area</h1>
      <pre id="compDisp">Currently no parts completed</pre>
    </div>
    
    <div class="display" id="screen4">
      <h1>Log Area</h1> 
      <pre id="logList"> </pre>
    </div>
    
    <script>
</script>
 </body>
 
</html>
```

Thank you again.

Comment: `switch (partsInput.value) {`?

Answer (score 0):

`const partsInput = document.getElementById("parts"); switch (partsInput) { case 'Gear':`

partsInput now contains an html element. In the switch statement, you are comparing it to strings. What you want to do is compare the value from the html element, because that contains the string you are looking for:

`switch (partsInput.value)`

docs: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_value.asp

Comment: When I add .value to partsInput for the switch statement, it still will not display the text I added for each case.  I moved the switch statement inside the function queuepart() so it will only run when the Add Part button is pressed.  I am sytill having trouble though.